# "No siehst Du." meaning

Tags: meaning, austrian, low-german

The sentence is simply "*No siehst Du*".

Anyone able to explain the meaning of "*no*"?

It may be Niederdeutsch / Austrian.

I cannot find it in any of the dictionaries I use.

Comment: This might be just a dialect pronunciation or spelling of "na": "Na, siehst Du".

Comment: Without context it's just wild guessing

Comment: About Niederdeutsch and Austrian read this question and answer: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/64609/1487

Comment: I'm not an expert, but a colleague from South Tirol some times, says "do" instead of "da", and of course in Bavarian the pronunciation of "na" sound more like a "no/noa".

Comment: @Medi1Saif: This is true for all Bavarian dialects (including the variation spoken in Italy), but in the same regions *»siehst du«* will shift to *»sixt«* or *»sigst«.* (There is no standard orthography for Bavarian dialects.) (The pronoun *du* is already included in the verb in Bavarian, similar to Latin, so you don't use an extra *»du«* here.) And so, it either is *»Na siehst du«* which is Standard German or *»No sigst«* which is Bavarian dialect. And in Low German it would be either *»Na süchst du«* or *»Na kiekst du«,* but I'm not sure, if *»na«* really stays *»na«* or if it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember a television series called "Mcloud" about a Taos Sheriff roaming around New York on a horse? Whenever he'd solved a case, he used a term "There ya go." which drove his boss crazy. It means roughly the same as “No siehst Du.”

You can drive linguistic experts up the wall with this kind of expression, because it doesn't really mean anything. Its a self confirmation. It rubs things in.

Answer (score 6):

I support Hennings answer translating this to "Na, siehst Du" in standard language. For a native speaker, it has a similar meaning like "I told you so".
BTW note that [Niederdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache) is geographically related to the north of Germany, in contrast to southern Germany / Austria.

Answer (score 4):

"No" ist hier einfach eine dialektale Aussprache von "na" und ist in verschiedenen Regionen Österreichs die gängige Aussprache. Das ist ein umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck. Sehr nett erklärt wird "na" mit Beispielen auf https://www.dwds.de/wb/na.

Im Normalfall würde man dieses Dialektwort nicht so in dieser Aussprache niederschreiben, beziehungsweise würde man dann "siehst du" auch so schreiben, wie es im Dialekt ausgesprochen wird.

I just realised, I should answer in English...
"no" is simply the dialect form of "na" which is a common and a widely spread spelling in different parts of Austria. It is colloquial German and means something like "well, you see?" A sort of emotional exclamation in connection with different words as companion.
Some of these translations can be seen also at [https://de.pons.com/übersetzung/deutsch-englisch/na](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/na) where you find different phrases with "na".
In general one would not write words in the way the are pronounced, or at least not in combination with a word that is not dialectal ("siehst du" is Standard German, not dialect).

Comment: Im zweiten Link ist ein Leerzeichen, dass da nicht hingehört. Ich kann leider kein Edit mit nur einem Zeichen vorschlagen.

Answer (score 1):

The dialect *No* could also mean *Noch*. ("Noch siehst Du" would mean someting like "You can still see").

If the *No* is supposed to be *Na* in standard german, I would expect a comma after it. But without further context it is impossible to say for sure.