# Low German, Upper German, Bavarian ... Where are these dialects spoken?

Tags: dialect, regional

There are many questions here on German.stackexchange dealing with variations of Standard German and with specific properties of dialects, but to many people it seems to be unclear in which geographic region which dialects are spoken.

So, here is my question:

What are the names of German dialects and in which regions are they spoken?

Comment: This question was inspired by [another question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/64600/1487) where someone thought that *Niederdeutsch* was spoken in Austria.

Comment: The answer here covers which dialects belong where linguistically in great detail. Unfortunately it does not give you a good ideaof what people actually speak in every day life. You will here a lot of Bavarian when in Munich and even more in rural parts of Bavaria. But this is not true in most other parts of Germany. It is 'Berlinerisch' to say 'ik' instead of 'ich' but today most people in Berlin would say 'ich'. The language spoken everyday in Germany outside of Bavaria is a lot closer to standard German than to the local dialects.

Comment: They should speak Low German at least in Low Austria to be consistent.

Comment: @VladimirF: There is no »Low Austria«. Austria is a federal nation like USA, Mexico or Germany. It consists of 9 states. One of them is *»Lower Austria«* (in German: *Niederösterreich*), and the dialects spoken in Lower Austria belong to *Danube Bavarian* which is one of the three variations of *Bavarian*, which belongs to *Upper German* which is a group of *High German* dialects.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast OK lower, I am used to the Czech or German names of those bundescountries. (It was supposed to be a pun...)

Answer (score 62):

When you talk about geographic borders of dialects, you talk about isoglosses.

### What is an isogloss?

An [isogloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogloss) is a geographic boundary between two linguistic features. One famous example of such an isogloss in Germany is the [Speyer line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyer_line). The German word *»Apfel«* (English: *apple*) is pronounced [ˈap͡fl̩] (like »apfl«) in Standard German and in dialects spoken south of this line, but in the dialects spoken north of this line people pronounce it as [ˈapl̩] (like »appl«), and so this line is also called the »Appel-Apfel-Linie«

### The Benrath line

More important is another isogloss, the so called [Benrath line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benrath_line) that roughly goes from Aachen in the west to Frankfurt/Oder in the east. The exact course is described in the German Wikipedia article about the [Benrather Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benrather_Linie).

In fact it’s not a single line, but a bunch of many closely located lines separating different linguistic features. One of them is the »maken-machen-Linie«: The German word *»machen«* (Engl: *to make*) is pronounced [ˈmaxn̩] in Standard German and in Dialects south of this line, but north of this line people say [ˈmakn̩]. And geographic almost (but not perfect) identic are other isoglosses: The *»ik-ich-Linie«,* the *»dat-das-Linie«,* the *»Dorp-Dorf-Linie«,* the *»hebben-haben-Linie«* and many others. These isoglosses are geographic so similar, and there are so many of them, that they were given a common name, and this is **Benrath line.** It is a rather sharp line, and all isoglosses that belong to it are only a few kilometers apart from each other.

### Niederdeutsch, Plattdeutsch (Low German, Low Saxon)

Dialects spoken north of the Benrath line are called **Niederdeutsch** or **Plattdeutsch.** In English you also have two names for it: **Low German** and **Low Saxon.** The name comes from the low and flat land where it is spoken.

There are Wikipedia articles available for it

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_German)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache)
- [in Low German](https://nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plattd%C3%BC%C3%BCtsch)

When you try to read the article about Low German in Low German, you will find, that it is very different from Standard German, and for this reason most linguists define Low German as a distinct language. But since it is spoken in an area where also Standard German is taught in schools and where all official documents are written in Standard German, almost every native speaker of Low German is bilingual and also speaks Standard German (although sometimes with a heavey Low German accent). And for the same reason there are dialects spoken in this region that are a mixture of Low German and Standard German.

I should also mention, that Low German is also spoken in the eastern regions of the Netherlands and that there are isoglosses running through the Low German region that separate it in smaller regions where different variations of Low German are spoken. And I should mention, that *Niederdeutsch, Plattdeutsch* and *Niedersächsisch* are not 100% identic to each other. There exist three different definitions for these three variations, but I’m not going to spread that out here. If your’re interested in this topic, you can read the Wikipedia articles.

### Hochdeutsch (High German)

When you move southwards through Germany, the sea level increases more and more, until you reach the alps in the south. And because the land south of the Benrath line is higher, the language spoken south of this line is called *»Hochdeutsch«.* But be very careful with this term, since it has two different meanings:

1. Hochdeutsch (High German) is a group of German dialects. It is not taught in schools, not used for official documents, and not used to print books and papers.
2. Hochdeutsch (Standard German) is a standardized cross-regional language taught in schools, used for official documents (like laws etc.), and used to print books and papers.

Here in this answer I consequently will use the term *»Hochdeutsch«* as defined in item 1, while I will use the term *»Standarddeutsch«* for what is described in item 2. The English terms *»High German«* and *»Standard German«* are much clearer.

There are Wikipedia articles available for it

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_languages)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsche_Dialekte)

Note, that the English article talks about High German **languages** while the German article describes them as **dialects.** This is because linguists have divergent opinions of what the difference between a language and a dialect might be.

But this questions topic is about the geographic properties of German dialects, so I keep with the term *»dialect«* and have a closer look at geographic properties, and here the Speyer line from paragraph 1 comes in handy, because it separates the High German region in two parts: *»Mitteldeutsch«* and *»Oberdeutsch«.*

### Mitteldeutsch (Central German)

Central German is the name for the group of dialects spoken between the Benrath line and the Speyer line. They are also spoken outside of Germany, in Luxemburg and parts of Belgium. And for this reason, German (Standard German to be clear) is also an official language in these two countries.

Also Central German can be subdivided by several isoglosses into smaller regions where sub-dialects of Central German are spoken, which differ strongly when you move from east (Dresden) to west (Köln = Cologne). For more details, please consult Wikipedia.

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_German)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitteldeutsche_Dialekte)

### Oberdeutsch (Upper German)

The dialects south of Speyer line are called *»Upper German«.* You can find it in Wikipedia:

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_German)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutsche_Dialekte)

You clearly can differentiate it from Central German and even more from Low German, but Upper German is so diverse and spread over such a big area, that it is divided in four languages or dialect groups, where one of them has become extinct 1000 years ago:

- Ost- und Südfränkisch (East and South Franconian)
- Alemannisch (Alemannic German)
- Bairisch (Bavarian)
- † Langobardisch (Lombardic)

Lombardic was spoken by the Lombards in northern regions of Italy, but it was spoken only between about 600 AD and 1000 AD. But the other three still living languages are worth a closer look:

### Ost- und Südfränkisch (East and South Franconian)

East Franconian is spoken for example in Nürnberg and Würzburg, South Franconian in Karlsruhe.

East Franconian has some properties in common with Central German, but still most linguists put it in the group of Upper German dialects. South Franconian more clearly belongs to Upper German.

Links to Wikipedia

- in English

  - [South Franconian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Franconian_German)
  - [East Franconian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Franconian_German)
- in Standard German

  - [Südfränkisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCdfr%C3%A4nkische_Dialekte)
  - [Ostfränkisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostfr%C3%A4nkische_Dialekte)

### Alemannisch (Alemannic German)

This group of dialects is spoken in many countries like France (in Alsace and the Canton of Phalsbourg), Liechtenstein (in the whole country) and Austria (in the state Vorarlberg), but the main regions are

- in Germany in South Baden (Südbaden, state of Baden-Württemberg) and Swabia (Schwaben, states of Baden-Württemberg and Bavaria)
- all German-speaking regions of Switzerland

There are Wikipedia articles about Alemannic German available

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannic_German)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Dialekte)
- [in Alemannic German](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannisch)

The status of Alemannic German in Germany is relatively clearly that of a group of dialects that are used in unofficial settings, like among friends or inside a family. But in Switzerland is has the status of a distinct language used parallel to the Standard German language.

In Switzerland Standard German language is almost only used for writing, but not to speak. When Swiss people speak, they use the Swiss variation of Alemannic German which they call *»Schwyzerdütsch«* (*Swiss German*). Radio and TV shows produced in Switzerland for Swiss people are produced in Swiss German which is unintelligible for most people outside of Switzerland.

Swiss German was used for writing among many centuries only in very rare cases and so it is not standardized (there are no official rules for orthography). But since Swiss people use SMS and boards on the internet, they about 20 years ago began to write no longer in Standard German but in Swiss German. And for this reason, Swiss German has of all languages and dialects discussed here the highest chances to survive also for the next 100 years, while all other versions of German slowly will become extinct in this century (as I believe) and will be replaced by Standard German.

Swiss German in Wikipedia:

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch)
- [in Alemannic German](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch)

### Bairisch (Bavarian)

This is the kind of German spoken in large areas of Bavaria (Altbayern), small parts in the west of Saxony, almost all of Austria (all states but Vorarlberg) and South Tyrol which is a region in the north of Italy (next to North Tyrol and East Tyrol which both belong to Austria).

Also Bavarian differs strongly from Standard German, so that it is unintelligible for many German native speakers living in northern regions. And so many linguists classify it not as a group of dialects, but as a distinct language.

And since it has so many speakers and is spread over a large geographic area, it also can be subdivided by isoglosses into regions with subvariations:

- Nordbairisch (North Bavarian), spoken only in Bavaria
- Mittel- or Donaubairisch (Middle or Danube Bavarian), spoken in Bavaria and Austria
- Südbairisch (South Bavarian) spoken only in small parts of Bavaria but large regions of Austria and in Italy.

Bavarian in Wikipedia:

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language)
- [in Standard German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairisch)
- [in Bavarian](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarisch)

---

### Standarddeutsch (Standard German)

I mentioned Standard German many times in my answer, so I think I should tell something about it too:

You very often will hear the term *»Hochdeutsch«* for Standard German, but this term is ambiguous, as explained earlier in this answer. Mainly in Switzerland you also will find the word *»Schriftdeutsch«* (*written German*) used for Standard German, because in Switzerland Standard German is very rarely used for speaking, mainly only for writing.

Standard German is what you learn when you learn German as a foreign language, but you should know, that it in some manner is an artificial language, because, as you will know, when you have read this answer so far, German is not *one* language. Over probably more than 15 centuries many different West-Germanic languages like Bavarian, Saxonian, Franconian, Alemannic, Lombardic etc. were spoken in the region where now is spoken the German language. And the modern German language developed from this mixture of different languages, and many attempts have been made to create a language that everybody could understand who lived in this region.

Among many attempts maybe Martin Luther’s translation of the Holy Bible into German was one of the biggest steps to create something like a standardized German.

This process has not come to an end yet. It is still going on, and it will only end in *one* German, when every German native speaker no longer speaks their local or regional dialect, but only standard German. This is the day when all languages discussed here will have become extinct.

### German standard variations

But now even the standard exists in three different flavours, the three standard variations of German. This is a layer above the layer of dialects, ignoring isoglosses that separate the historic grown borders between dialects. The borders of the three standard variations are political borders between nations.

We have:

- **German Standard German**
  used in Germany, Belgium and Luxemburg
  Wikipedia: [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Standard_German); [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesdeutsches_Hochdeutsch)
- **Austrian Standard German**
  used in Austria and Italy (South Tyrol)
  Wikipedia: [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_German); [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch)
- **Swiss Standard German**
  used in Switzerland and Liechtenstein
  Wikipedia: [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Standard_German); [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer_Hochdeutsch)

So, what does *used* mean in this context? It means that laws and other official documents are written in these variations, and it means, that these variations are taught in schools. Also regional newspapers are printed in these variations, and politicians and news speakers use these variations.

But books are (except some rare exceptions) only printed in German Standard German. This is, because about 85% of all German native speakers live in Germany, and German people don’t know Austrian or Swiss Standard German. But every German native speaker in Austria and Switzerland knows German Standard German and can understand it.

Comment: There are also a number of German varieties spoken outside Europe. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_languages#Family) has a handy summary. What counts as "German" and what doesn't is of practical importance here since it may determine which questions are off-topic for this site. The [AdA](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) is a useful resource for locating various isoglosses in the German speaking region.

Comment: Are there attempts to track how close the German language is to full unification? I imagine it got a lot more unified over the past 50 years thanks to internal and external migration but by how much?

Comment: @PiedPiper: I think the answer is already quite long. The region where Low German is spoken is about as big as Switzerland, Austria and South Tyrol together. So, when I start to describe the alpine dialects more detailed, I also have to use the same degree of detail for the dialects spoken in Germany, and then my answer would become way too long.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Language is mainly spoken language. Writing is just a way to preserve a text, and the methods of conservation, i.e. orthography and typography, are completely unified, with two exceptions: The letter »ß« (named »Eszett« in German German but »scharfes S« in Austrian German) does not exist in Swiss German and is replaced by »ss« in Swiss German. The other exception are the special quoting marks that I use. They are called »Chevrons« in German and Austrian German and they point inwards in these two languages. In Swiss German they are called «Guillemets» and point outwards. ...

Comment: ... other differences in orthography are just a result of different pronunciation, and I know only one word that is written different in German German and Austrian German, and this is the word *Geschoß/Geschoss* (in Engl.: projectile or bullet, but also floor/level of a building). In Austrian German the vowel »o« is spoken as a long vowel, while in German German it is short. But the length of a vowel decides if after it will come *ß* or *ss*. ...

Comment: ... so, while orthography and typography already are completely unified (with the named exceptions), spoken language still is far away from being *one* German. There are so many differences, that you can fill many books with them (what some people really did), So this format here is not appropriate to list all the many differences. But I have linked many Wikipedia articles in my answer, and if you are interested in the still existing differences, these articles will help you to find most of them. ...

Comment: ... I want to add some words about another phenomenon: People living in Switzerland and Austria are exposed to German Standard German every single day in their life, because most of them watch German TV stations, they read books and magazines in German German and almost al content on internet that is available in German is produced in German German. People in Germany on the other hand get in contact with Swiss of Austrian German only when they make holidays in these countries, and then most of them believe, that the language we speak here is a dialect, even if we speak Standard German. ...

Comment: So, almost everybody living in Switzerland and Austria speaks three languages: 1. The local dialect, 2. The national Standard, 3. German Standard German. (And 4. English, but this is another topic). And many immigrants from Germany living in Austria or Switzerland are not aware of the existence of standard variations, and they believe that only they speak Standard German, and some of them really try to teach us how to use our own language correctly, and it sometimes its really hard to convince German immigrants thats its them who have to learn a new language when they live in a foreign country

Comment: (+1) Standard German is very much spoken in Switzerland, on the radio, for the evening news on TV, in parliament, to address foreigners and German-speaking Swiss people whose native language is French or Italian (when not using English of French). Those are very specific contexts (Switzerland was offered as one of the defining cases of “diglossia”) but I don't think it's completely accurate to say that (Swiss) Standard German is *very* rarely used for speaking.

Comment: In particular, it's not true that local radio and TV shows are produced in (some variant of) Swiss German. For example I always found *Die Rundschau* fascinating. It is very much geared towards a local audience (it deals with Swiss politics and is not, AFAIK, broadcasted elsewhere), the moderators switch between different dialects over the course of the broadcast, introductions and voice-overs are in Standard German and then the same moderator switches to Swiss German for the studio interview. When the interviewee is a French speaker (e.g. Albert Baehny), they speak Standard German.

Comment: Is "Standard Deutsch" Standard-Deutsch?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I agree, I've deleted my suggestion.

Comment: Nitpick: "When you move southwards through Germany, the sea level increases more and more" → Thankfully, the sea level does not depend on where you are in Germany, otherwise you would be causing floods all the time ;-) You mean the "terrain level" or something like that.

Comment: "most linguists define Low German as a distinct language" – Most linguists, I believe, agree that the distinction between language and dialect is arbitrary from a scientific standpoint and more driven by politics than by facts. "A language is a dialect with a Navy" is a saying I have heard from linguists.

Comment: Good answer.  It would be even better with a map.  There should be many maps around, some of which may even be free.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Max Weinreich, "Der YIVO un di problemen fun undzer tsayt", *YIVO Bleter*, Vol. 25, No. 1, Jan-Feb 1945. The statement, originally in Yiddish, is commonly transcribed as: "a shprakh iz a dialekt mit an armey un flot".

Comment: @mkrieger1: or "altitude" or "elevation" or "height above sea level" (just suggestions)

Comment: There was an *suggested edit* in the queue concerning the mapping of Alemannic in Germany which I tried to resolve in line with the following: In some parts of Baden-Württemberg (North Baden), not Alemannic but Frankonian dialects are spoken. Swabia, on the other hand, belongs to Baden-Württemberg *and* Bavaria.

Answer (score 7):

There is literally an english-language Wikipedia page including a nice map that answers this question:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_dialects

[image]