# Meaning of "Abfahrt" in German slang

Tags: slang

What is the meaning of the word "Abfahrt" in the context of this song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfVK9z7BlUM

I know the word to literally mean departure, exit, descent, etc, but it's used in FiNCH's music and seems to carry a specific meaning that I don't understand.

In English if a song was titled "Departure" and comprised those kinds of lyrics I'd probably have a guess at what it means but I wanted to be sure...

Comment: Although Finch Asozial was born in Frankfurt (Oder), I think the use of "Abfahrt" has nothing to do with East German slang. The song says "he's my East German morning sun [...] he's from Lichtenberg not West Berlin". Lichtenberg is a district of Berlin which belonged to East Berlin before the German reunification. The German parts of the song are more or less Standard German with a few fragments of Berlin dialect. But there is no use of "typical" East German slang.

Comment: @PaulFrost *Seine größtenteils satirisch anmutenden Texte sind oftmals in vulgärer Sprache verfasst und geprägt von Ostalgie und einer größtenteils positiven Einstellung gegenüber dem modernen Ostdeutschland* ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finch_Asozial)) I agree with you, that he does not use a special slang, but he clearly has some connection to Eastern Germany.

Comment: And here is the [link to read the text](https://genius.com/Finch-abfahrt-lyrics), without need to look the whole video ;)

Comment: According to one of my more illiterate and perhaps simpleminded colleagues, Abfahrt must also be "probably the largest city" in Germany. He came to this conclusion along the Autobahn in our rental car, and proceeded to present it, absent of any reflection on his part.

Comment: @StianYttervik The largest German city is not *Abfahrt*, but *[Ausfahrt](https://www.bilderbox.com/image/Ausfahrt-Schild-auf-einer-Autobahn-101129.html)*. Also [this city](https://www.colourbox.de/vektor/verkehrsschild-achtung-stau-vektor-6784408) is very big.

Comment: @PaulFrost You are, of course, right. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulFrost _"Oh, Püppi, Du schmeckst so jut, Ick liebe deinen Duft, Meene kleene Zuckerschnute"_ - sounds pretty Ostdeutsch to me...

Comment: I take the point though that "Abfahrt" doesn't seem to have any particular east-german meaning so I've removed that from the title.

Comment: @quant *Püppi, jut, ick, meene kleene Zuckerschnute* belong to *Berlinerisch*, but that happens to be a *Metrolekt* with weak ties to the surrounding varieties. Even though Berlin is geographically situated in the Eastern half, its idiom is not specific for East Germany. Sometimes *Saxonian* is mistaken for *the* Eastern German™ as well, but because of the [big north-south differences](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/64609/), there is not much common ground for 'Eastern German dialects' in general, e.g. between *Mecklenburgisch* and *Vogtländisch*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus that's helpful thanks, I don't think I understood the distinction between east german and east berlin.

Comment: @quant (whole) Berlin is located in the former GDR, what now is common called Eastern Germany (or "neue Bundesländer"). But Berlin itself was also divided (because the valuable capital city) into Eastern and Western part (in parts by the Berliner Wall), only the eastern belonged to the GDR, the other was some kind of enclave of the old BRD, now called "alte Bundesländer" or simple Western Germany. So the dialect spoken in nowadays Berlin is not some kind of Easter-Germany-dialect, but strongly identified as "Berlinerisch" (Berlin dialect).

Comment: @quant Berlin has a so-called *Metrolekt* which is notably different from all Eastern German *dialects*, even though it may have influenced the adjacent ones. Furthermore, since the *Metrolekt* is much older than the city's division and thus has been spoken in then West Berlin as well (to a somewhat lesser extent though) -- which was not part of the historical *East Germany* (GDR) -- *Berlinerisch* is not what would usually be called an *ostdeutscher* dialect, at least not in the historical or in the linguistical sense. It's kind of outside of the dialect systematics.

Answer (score 14):

"Abfahrt" seems to be a slang expression for partying in the realm of techno music, possibly also refering to drug use. The newspaper *taz* [mentions the word as early as 1998](https://taz.de/Die-serioese-Techno-Abfahrt/!1354216/) in an article about a Berlin club. In 2021, a lot of merchandise with the word *Abfahrt* can be found in online shops, too.

Four meanings of "Abfahrt that I'm aware of might have been alluded to when using the word in this context first. There may be even more and it's a question of interpretation whether they were intentional:

1. "Abfahrt!" is obviously mainly used in the sense of "Let's go!", "Let's get started!" in the video. It was already used in that sense for a long time when starting a literal trip in a car. This meaning is easily understandable even if you  don't know the word from the context of techno.
   Also, drug lingo has always used words like *trip* for the experience of drug effects. Also see @Hobbamok's answer on *fahren*.
2. The video also alludes to *Abfahrtsski* which means *downhill skiing*. *Die Abfahrt* in this sense is the descent on ski which is obviously also a good metaphor for partying or amphetamine use.
3. *Auf etwas/jemanden abfahren* means "to dig something/somebody".
4. An exit from a highway is called *Abfahrt*, which could be associated to being close to approaching the destination, or to leave the popular path.

Comment: Gute Auflistung, aber für Punkt 4 sehe ich keine Anhaltspunkte beim Video, von dem ich nach 3 Minuten aber auch genug hatte. Für Punkt 3 spricht nur wenig, trotz des "massive things". "Auf jmd./etw. abfahren" ist verbreitet, aber als Substantiv habe ich es in dem Kontext noch nicht gehört.

Answer (score 8):

In slang „Abfahrt“ is used to describe starting excessively celebrating or „partying until it drops“, i.e., in the context of the song, taking drugs, dancing in (and on) ecstasy, and generally misbehaving.

Answer (score 6):

A short introduction on the word level:

- *fahren* means 'to go by means of transports', 'to drive' or 'to ride' (whereas *gehen* is going by foot).
- ***ab**fahren* (and ***ab**gehen*, accordingly) literally means 'to go **off**'
- *Abfahrt* (resp. *Abgang*) is the corresponding noun, literally meaning 'the go-off' (= start, departure etc.)

That being said, *Abfahrt* belongs to a **figurative semantic field with *abgehen* in its center** that is used to express 'to **go** down' (note the similarity), 'all hell was let loose', 'to whoop it up', 'to paint the town red' etc. It's probably cognate to the idea of *let's **go*** in English:

- *Jetzt geht's ab* (also *… geht die Post ab*) means 'now it's happening', 'now it's going down'
- *abgehen* figuratively means 'to go wild'
- *Abfaaaaaahrt!* is a common fire-up slogan by carnival barkers on fairground rides. Maybe because of that, *Abfahrt* has been a joking expression for *let's go* in other contexts.

It's notable that as a verb, only *abgehen* is used in the figurative sense, the corresponding noun *Abgang* is not. Inversely, the noun *Abfahrt* is used figuratively (maybe originating in the fairground rides), but not its verb *abfahren*.

In the song, it is also used like on fairground rides to fire the listeners up for the forthcoming drop of the song (like a 'rave signal'). The best translation in this context is probably just *let's go*, but nevertheless *Abfahrt* conveys many more connations (concerning *going wild*) as stated above.

Comment: "Mach' mal 'nen Abgang!" sowie "Ist das abgefahren!" sind Gegenbeispiele.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sure there is *mach nen Abgang!* ('go away!'), however its meaning is different from *geh ab!* ('go wild!'); hence I wouldn't count it to the same semantic field. *Abgefahren*, on the other hand, seems to be another good example for it.

Answer (score 2):

**(almost) Everyone here is completely missing the point, (or at least a very very important connotation)**

"Abfahrt" *in the specific context of this song* comes from "fahren" in "es fährt", a slang term used to describe the moment that a certain subset of drugs (stimulants, mostly MDMA/Ecstacy) hit. This would be quite an unusual interpretation since this use of the word is incredibly niche and somewhat unusual, **BUT** the entire song is talking about doing drugs - pills to be specific - which means that the song is directly speaking in the context of this subculture.

Do note that this translation can not be used in regular speech outside of techno clubs, as evidenced by the fact that everyone else here missed it

Comment: Welcome to German SE! I'm wondering if this usage ever been documented somewhere else, e.g. online, in literature or in a more unambigous way in lyrics? Have you heard it personally? The logical reason for the question is: if it is *incredibly* niche, it would maybe not occur in a song. However, if Finch knows it and it is understood by a notable share of the audience, shouldn't it then appear somewhere else, too?

Comment: @amadeusamadeus blatantly stealing from another comment: https://taz.de/Die-serioese-Techno-Abfahrt/!1354216/ and: it's not really as unambiguous. The entire song is constantly all the time talking about drugs. Literally every sinlge one of Finchs lines (I checked, no exception) refers to taking party drugs. And the line "genau wenn die Murmel klatscht" references exactly this very moment when we'd say "es fährt", because that's the moment it hits.

Comment: To add to this: Finch (or his character) is a) from Berlin, Germanys party capital and b) from a lower class, exactly the one you'd picture excessively taking pills on a rave. Also: here is a Swiss-German Newspaper using the phrase: https://www.nzz.ch/zuerich/kokain-in-zuerich-da-koennten-sie-geradeso-gut-menschliches-blut-trinken-ld.150981, so while it is incredibly niche slang, it does crop up. Just very rarely due to the nature of the topic

Comment: I absolutely agree that *Abfahrt* in the song could also mean *the drugs kick in*, however I'm still wondering whether *es fährt* is a common expression on its own, because the linked texts feature only the forms "Abfahrt" (Germany) and "es fährt ein" (Switzerland). I also found another reference for ["es fährt ab"](https://ktnv1.orf.at/stories/453595) (Austria) as for a drug. So I'd believe you if you said that you've heard the phrase *es fährt* used in that way, but right now I still have the impression that *Abfahrt* in the song is derived from generic *abgehen* or *auf etw. abfahren*.

Comment: PS: *einfahren* is simply a Helvetism, e.g. *"Plötzlich kam Bert eingefahren, zusammen mit seiner Freundin."* [1](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idForum=2&idThread=1030799&lp=ende&lang=de), also used for the upcoming of the effects of drugs: *"Grüner Tee [hält] den Suchtmittel-Spiegel besser. Es fährt langsam ein und hält länger an"* [2](https://derstandard.de/permalink/p/1026113315); *"ein getränk [sic] dass [sic] wirklich heimtückisch einfährt :-)"* [3](https://www.pauker.at/pauker/DE_SS/SC/fo/18/64). So we still have *(auf etw.) abfahren*, *Abfahrt* and Swiss *einfahren*.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is to feel not comfortable with the circumstances that have been talked about before.

Let's imagine you are a religious person and someone tries to convience you that there exists no one like god and nothing will happen after death than you can say the word "Abfahrt" to this one because of the reason that you don't believe in his opinion.

To say "Abfahrt" is the same as letting the others know that you don't give a shit on his doubts.

By the way Frankfurt (Oder) is a town in the eastern part of Germany in the so called *neuen Bundesländer*. The Frankfurt (Main) which you means is in west of Germany.

Comment: Good, but not applicable in the songs context